# How to use Flex-wrap to wrap the 6th box to next line

Tags: css, flexbox

My goal is I want my boxes in the first line are 5 rows and the 6th box will go to the next row? Can you show me how to do it?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make them all 20% wide?

Comment: More details needed. Can the boxes be any width, as long as there are just five per row?

Comment: It would help if you add a more thorough explanation, or, better, a visual one like an image or similar of your expected result.

Comment: So far this is an ill-defined problem. Are all the boxes to be the same width? Is there a constant gap between them? What defines the width of container?

Comment: Flex-wrap only works when `screen-size` is changed or is smaller than the actual width of `flex-box`. It should not be used to create table like structure. Use grid-layout for this. Check the answer given by **TimR**

Answer (score 0):

[Flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) is a one-dimensional layout method for arranging items in rows *or* columns. Items flex (grow or shrink) to fill the available space.

[Grid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Grids) is a two-dimensional layout system that lets you lay content out in rows *and* columns. I believe Grid is the better choice for your intentions.

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to fix the issue you are having.

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    gap: 30px;
}
.box {
    width: calc(20% - 30px); //minus the gap
    background: #ffd6d6
}
.box:nth-of-type(even) {
    background: #fafafa;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```

You could also give the `.container` class a `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto` to make this responsive. Or use Bootstrap which uses flex box containers with build is resposive features and a ton more.

Answer (score -1):

Your title and description are contradictive, I'm assuming you want 5 columns, and when 5 columns are placed, the new items wrap onto the next wrap.

Set the `flex-basis` equivalent to the value to 100 / what column the wrap should happen at (100 / 6) = 16.66%):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 0 16.66%;
  height: 50px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="box">2</div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
  <div class="box">4</div>
  <div class="box">5</div>
  <div class="box">6</div>
  <div class="box">7</div>
  <div class="box">8</div>
  <div class="box">9</div>
  <div class="box">10</div>
  <div class="box">11</div>
  <div class="box">12</div>
</div>
```